# How to put a svg :before state

Tags: css, state

I want to put a svg before a div element in Oxy, I tried it with css but I failed because I am still learning css.

I hope the image makes sense. I want to put the SVG where the arrow points to svg.

Thanks for your time already,

Best regards,

Mark

[image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2PJy.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and consider updating your post with a [mre] of your code. We can't troubleshoot your code if we can't access it :)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, it would be better to _show_ your code with a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

As promised here is what I used.

```
.pseudo--code:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: url("https://images-svg.svg");
  width: 10em;
    max-height: 100%;
  left: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  opacity; .1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic structure to achieve what you need.

```
<body>
    <div class='outter-container'>
        <h2>Some headline</h2>
            <div class='inner-container'>
                <svg>SVG goes here</svg>
                <div class='text-button-container'>
                    <p>Some text here</p>
                    <button>Click me</button>
                </div> 
            </div> 
    </div>    
</body>
```

To style it, you will need to apply CSS.

```
.outter-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is right, I want it as a pseudo element in the before:state

Comment: Sorry, but it's not possible with a pseudo element. Pseudo elements are used in CSS for stylization.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is not true. I managed to do it, I will put the solution here later when I am on my laptop.

Comment: As promised here is what I used.